# Switch back to original thread after executing element of a chain

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

Is it possible to achieve something like this with RxJava, and if so - how:

1. There is chain of Rx operators, which is subscribed to with proper `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`
2. Inside the chain, there is a need to execute something on particular scheduler (different from those mentioned above)
3. After the above p2 is executed, chain must continue on whatever schedulers specified as part of subscription

Comment: I don't understand you. There is no standard way of going back to the same thread pool within a scheduler unless it is the `single()` scheduler or the `mainThread()` on Android. There is an extension library with a shared scheduler implementation: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#sharedscheduler .

Comment: Very interesting, checking the lib - thanks. Yes it's clear with single and mainThread.

Comment: @akarnokd thank you I could certainly use the lib (it works well) but I searched heavily and looks like there is no reliable way to get "current" scheduler for given chain constituent, so the alternative would be inject scheduler from outside but than I can get along without SharedScheduler, using pair of before/after observeOn's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Just use the `observeOn()` operator multiple times.

Example:

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.Schedulers;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<Long> source = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        source.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(i -> {
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " map1: " + i);
                    return i;
                })
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map(i -> {
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " map2: " + i);
                    return i;
                }).subscribe();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

[image]

You can see that the two map operation happened in two different threads.